# How to know if browser is embedded in other application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-detection

I work with an extension from Sketchup that opens a webdialog ( from the default OS browser - in windows is IE, but without menu and other bars ), but this page can be acessed by a browser(not embedded - can be all browsers).
I need know (with javascript/jquery)  if the user browser is embedded in another application.
Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, this will detect if a page is loaded in an iframe

```
if (window!=window.top) { /* I'm in a frame! */ }
```

Comment: I tried this, but returns always the self answer form the function


if(window!=window.top)
alert("XXX");
else
alert("YYY");

Comment: Its not  an Iframe, it is a browser embebbed in other application(eg. Sketchup, Real Player), and I need to know if its embedded, not when loads an iframe

Answer (score 0):

Check userAgent.  In SketchUp 16.1 on Mac for example, navigator.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) **SketchUp/16.1** (Mac; Safari)"